# determine Django User-id from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-models

is there any Way to determine the Django User-id from javascript?
i tried lot of solutions but without success.

**views.py**:

```
user_list=User.objects.all()
```

**TableModule.js**:

```
var users="{{user_list}}";
var username= window.localStorage.username;
var user_id;
for(int i=0;i<users.size;i++){
if(users[i].username == username){
  user_id=users[i].id;
  return
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you not get it using your view?

Comment: yes i can but how can i access it from javascript ?

Comment: I'm curious why you would need this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking to do is get the user's info in your view and return it in the view's context. Once that is done, you can assign it to a javascript variable like any other Django variable using the  `{{ my_var }}` notation.

Your view.py

```
def mysampleview(request):
    ...
    current_user_id = request.user.id
    context['current_user_id'] = current_user_id
    ...
    # Then return your context
```

yourjs.js

```
var user_id = {{ current_user_id }};
....
```

Comment: i tried your solution as described but when i try to show the id in alert dialog like this       var user_id = '{{ current_user_id }}'; m.alert(user_id); i get as output: { current_user_id }} but not the id

Comment: Well you'd need to this in a file that was rendered by the Django template engine, clearly.

Comment: To make sure that you are returning properly the users id, try to render it first in your html. Example: <p> {{ current_user_id }}</p>

Comment: Also, to be correct in this example, you would need to do this:

import json;
context['current_user_id'] = json.dumps(current_user_id)

That is, the value stored in the context variable would need to contain the json version of the value - not simply the userid.

Comment: @TheBigC and how can i get this Value in javascript? because var user_id = {{ current_user_id }}; dont do that!

Comment: If you just want to get the value of the user's ID and not the user's object, json is not needed.

Comment: @user3232446: Have you managed to render any django variable in a template. If you are having difficulties with this, I would advise you to go over the Django tutorial again.

Comment: @TheBigC nonsense. An ID is an integer; no need to convert it to JSON.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Django has a pluggable model architecture or authentication, and making the assumption that an id is an integer isn't always a good one.  Furthermore, while one might infer that the person asking the question is using django.contrib.auth, there's no evidence in the question that it's the case.  IMHO, encoding the value is "safer" in the long run.